# Go Project Compilation Issue with C Language Source Files

Tags: go, compilation

I am currently facing a compilation issue in my Go project, encountering errors related to C language source files. The specific errors include "expected identifier, found %" in the following files:

```
internal/abi/abi_test.s
internal/cpu/cpu_x86.s
sync/atomic/asm.s
crypto/subtle/xor_amd64.s
crypto/internal/boring/sig/sig_amd64.s
runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.s
```

The errors seem to be occurring during the assembly phase of the compilation process. The Go version I am using is go1.20.13. I intend to seek assistance on Stack Overflow to address this issue.

Any guidance or insights on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I expected know why

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering issues with assembly (.s) files in your Go project, particularly for the AMD64 architecture. The error message "expected identifier, found %" typically indicates a syntax error in the assembly code.
And also Verify that the assembly code is compatible with the version of the assembler and compiler you are using.